# Adding arrays to a timeline and summing them

Tags: microsoft-excel, array

I am trying to add multiple arrays to a simple timeline and then summing those arrays.  This is a simplified view:

```
A =  1   2   3   4   5

timeline    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7   8    9    10
---------------------------------------------------------------
A@ 2                  1    2    3    4    5
A@ 4                            1    2    3    4   5 
2A @ 6                                    2    4   6    8    10

Total       0    0    1    2    4    6    10   8  11    8    10
```

The matrix is labeled "A" and the timeline is sequential (0, 1, 2..)

I added a row for adding each matrix to the timeline and then a sum total row.

Question:  Is there a way to do this with matrix formulas so that I can do it all in one total row?

eg.

```
timeline    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7   8    9    10
---------------------------------------------------------------
                      1         1         2      
Total       0    0    1    2    4    6    10   8  11    8    10
```

Update:  I was hoping to find a way to use Excel matrix functions using key combination Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

I have a more complex problem where I'm trying to sum and scale a series of "startup ramps" for sales people based on their hire date.  Am trying to use a a hire date which adds a matrix (actually a vector) to the timeline and scales them (based on heads hired) and then sums them monthly.   Is there another way to approach this that I"m not thinking about?

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, Microsoft Excel cannot work with matrices this way.  If you rephrase your question it may be easier for us to find a suitable workaround.

Comment: Thank you.  Not sure I can rephrase if it doesn’t do it.   Could it be done with macros?

Comment: I added a little bit more about the problem I'm trying to solve in the above.